Why does wsimport say: "wdsl is not a part of this compilation"
While trying to create JAX-WS (version 3.0.2) client artifacts using wsimport I'm getting:

[wsimport] [ERROR] "file:/home/myuser/wsimport_test/src/resource/TestWdsl.wsdl" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:/home/myuser/wsimport_test/src/resource/xsd/item.xsd"?
[wsimport]   line 7 of file:/home/myuser/wsimport_test/src/resource/bindings_async.xml

Here is the command (generated by ant):

[wsimport] command line: wsimport-d /home/myuser/wsimport_test/build/ws/classes -keep -s /home/myuser/wsimport_test/build/ws/src -verbose /home/myuser/wsimport_test/src/resource/TestWdsl.wsdl -p com.wsimporttest.client -b /home/myuser/wsimport_test/src/resource/bindings_async.xml

The bindings_async.xml looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="3.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="TestWdsl.wsdl" node="wsdl:definitions">
        <jaxb:package name="com.testwsimport.app"/>
        <jaxb:enableAsyncMapping>true</jaxb:enableAsyncMapping>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

The files mentioned in the log exist and are placed in correct locations:
folder tree screenshot
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
I googled already a little bit and saw suggestions, that schemaLocation attribute is very sensitive to how one passes the value and that it should be maybe contain a path, not only the filename, so I tried it like this:
schemaLocation="./TestWdsl.wsdl"
and even like this:
schemaLocation="xsd/../TestWdsl.wsdl"
I tried a lot of such variants (absolute path as well) but didn't work.
